# how to change orientation of a particular portion of a View iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to change orientation of lower half of my view similar to stock app in which when we change the orientation of device only the Graph view of the same rotates. Please let me know how I would achieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a [CAAffineTransform](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) to any view independently causing it to rotate to any arbitrary degree regardless of the device orientation.

However, system views such a the keyboard appear rotated with the device and not the view i.e. if you rotate a text field, the keyboard will appear in the device orientation not the text fields transformed orientation.